# Opening Excel using EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, epplus

I'm trying to open an excel file that I wrote using epplus.

I'm opening it using this and it works in development server but not after publishing it.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Server.MapPath("~\chart.xlsx"))
```

How can i open this excel sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is trying to open the Excel file **on the server**. Even if you have Excel installed on the server, there probably won't be anyone sitting in front of the server to see it.

I suspect you want to open the file **on the client**:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=chart.xlsx")
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/chart.xlsx"))
Response.End()
```

You also need to bear in mind that there could be multiple users accessing your application at the same time. If you're generating the `chart.xlsx` file dynamically, the file for one request could overwrite the file for another request. It would be better to save the file directly to the response:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=chart.xlsx")
YourExcelPackage.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream)
Response.End()
```